# Field Grouping for a Kafka Spout

Tags: apache-storm, apache-kafka

Can field grouping be done on tuples emitted by a kafka spout? If yes, then how does Storm gets to know the fields in a Kafka record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka Spout declared its output fields like any other component. My explanation is based on current [implementation](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka) of KafkaSpout.

In KafkaSpout.java class we see declareOutputFields method that call getOutputFields() method of KafkaConfig Scheme.

```
@Override
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    declarer.declare(_spoutConfig.scheme.getOutputFields());
}
```

By default, KafkaConfig uses [RawMultiScheme](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/master/storm-core/src/jvm/backtype/storm/spout/RawMultiScheme.java) that implements this method in this way.

```
  @Override
  public Fields getOutputFields() {
    return new Fields("bytes");
  }
```

So what does it mean?, if you declared bolt which reads tuples from KafkaSpout with fieldGrouping you know that **every tuple that contains equals field "bytes" is going to be executed by the same task.**  If you want to emit any field, you should implement new scheme for your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Field grouping (and grouping in general) in Storm is for bolts, not for spouts. This is done via `InputDeclarer` class.
When you call `setBolt()` on `TopologyBuilder`, `InputDeclarer` is returned.

Comment: My bad, I meant it for the bolt.
That is I have a kafka spout which will emit the tuples to the subsequent bolts. Now for the kafka spout included in storm distribution, i must first know the fields emitted by it. Do these field ids are the same as they were published by the kafka publisher ?

Answer (score 0):

***TL:DR***
The default implementation of KafkaSpout declares following output fields in `declareOutputFields`:

`new Fields("topic", "partition", "offset", "key", "value");`

So in building topology code directly do:

```
topologyBuilder.setSpout(spoutName, mySpout, parallelismHintSpout);
topologyBuilder.setBolt(boltName, myBolt, parallelismHintBolt).fieldsGrouping(spoutName, new Fields("key"));
```

Details: A little looking into code tells that:

In Kafka Spout, `declareOutputFields` is [implemented](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/5f9fabc22e0741e62aa0c96c150709ccae74b9e8/external/storm-kafka-client/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/kafka/spout/KafkaSpout.java#L672) in following way:

```
@Override
public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
    RecordTranslator<K, V> translator = kafkaSpoutConfig.getTranslator();
    for (String stream : translator.streams()) {
        declarer.declareStream(stream, translator.getFieldsFor(stream));
    }
}
```

It gets fields from `RecordTranslator` interface and its instance is fetched from `kafkaSpoutConfig` i.e. `KafkaSpoutConfig<K, V>`. `KafkaSpoutConfig<K, V>` extends from `CommonKafkaSpoutConfig` (this is slightly different in 1.1.1 version though). The builder of this [returns](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/5f9fabc22e0741e62aa0c96c150709ccae74b9e8/external/storm-kafka-client/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/kafka/spout/internal/CommonKafkaSpoutConfig.java#L120) `DefaultRecordTranslator`. If you check the Fields in this class [implementation](https://github.com/apache/storm/blob/5f9fabc22e0741e62aa0c96c150709ccae74b9e8/external/storm-kafka-client/src/main/java/org/apache/storm/kafka/spout/DefaultRecordTranslator.java#L28), you will find:

```
public static final Fields FIELDS = new Fields("topic", "partition", "offset", "key", "value");
```

So we can use `Fields("key")` directly in fields grouping in topology code:

```
topologyBuilder.setBolt(boltName, myBolt, parallelismHintBolt).fieldsGrouping(spoutName, new Fields("key"));
```