# How to do Fields Grouping in Kafka Spout (JAVA)?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm

-
I've a requirement where I consume delta updates of Items from Kafka Queue partitions.

- Producer makes sure that all delta updates corresponding to a given item are available in same partition and in order.
  Ex: I1 & I2 are items, There updates say I1-Up1, I1-Up2 will be in same partition.Similarly, I2-Up1 & I2-Up2 will be in same partition.
- Hence, when my First set of Bolts receive they should get Fields grouped based on items( I1 and I2). I mean, the same bolt should receive all updates of I1 in order.
- The problem is How I can specify this in Bolt right after the Spout as KafkaSpout needs to do something.
- A quick search said I can write my own Kafka Scheme(implement MultiScheme), but lacks code examples.
  I've written one but not sure how to make sure it does Fields Grouping.

Comment: The problem is already solved at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26041614.
It should help you.